# Distribute a list of elements into 3 lists with different exclusions

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have a list of ~100,000 unique IDs and I need to distribute them into 3 lists so that each list gets ~33,000 of them.

The tricky part is that each of those lists has ~20k of the unique IDs that they can't use: an exclusion list.  Those 3 exclusion lists overlap by 15%-50% and vary in size, but in the end, there are more than enough of the original list to go around for 33% each, after exclusions.

```
biglist = [] #100k elements
a_exc = [] #15k elements in common w/biglist
b_exc = [] #25k elements in common w/biglist
c_exc = []  #30k elements in common w/biglist

# function to distribute biglist into a_list, b_list, and c_list 
# such that no element in a_list is in a_exc, etc.
# but all elements in biglist are distributed if possible not in all 3 exc lists
# and a/b/c are equal in size or as close to equal as possible
```

Because the exclusion lists overlap, it's not as simple as distributing to each list in sequence.  For what it's worth, I have a bunch of these that I have to work through, and I need to add them all up iteratively.  In some cases, the exclusion lists are each ~50% of the larger list, and can overlap each other by ~50% max.

Here's some test code to show the problem with 1/10th as many elements for speed's sake (doing this for 100k and 30k took awhile on my CPU).  When I run this, I consistently get ~3333, 3333, 2450 for all 3 elements, which is similar to the spread I get when running it for larger lists.

```
import random

def lst_maker(num):
    l = []
    for i in range(num):
      a = random.randint(1000000000, 9999999999)
      while a in l:
        a = random.randint(1000000000, 9999999999)
      l.append(a)
    return l

def exc_maker(inl, num):
    l = []
    for i in range(num):
        a = random.choice(inl)
        while a in l:
            a = random.choice(inl)
        l.append(a)
    return l


biglist = lst_maker(10000)

a_exc = exc_maker(biglist, 3000)
b_exc = exc_maker(biglist, 3000)
c_exc = exc_maker(biglist, 3000)

def distribute_3(lst):
    lst = set(lst)
    lst = list(lst)
    ll = len(lst)//3
    random.shuffle(lst)
    a = []
    b = []
    c = []
    for e in lst:
            if e not in a_exc and len(a) < ll:
                a.append(e)
            elif e not in b_exc and len(b) < ll:
                b.append(e)
            elif e not in c_exc and len(c) < ll:
                c.append(e)
    return a, b, c

a_list, b_list, c_list = distribute_3(biglist)

print len(a_list), len(b_list), len(c_list)
```

Comment: Can you include samples of the lists? A full [mcve].

Comment: They're long lists of phone numbers being used by call centers and none of them would be within compliance to release in full or part.  The exclusion lists are Do Not Call lists that vary by call center.  I'm trying to redistribute leads effectively.  To replicate, one could generate 100k ten-digit numbers, then distribute ~30k at random to each exclusion list, allowing duplicates.

Comment: It's good practice and expected etiquette to include full examples on StackOverflow. Asking potential helpers to replicate your data is not likely to receive much help. It would be good if you could create a sample list for each element, though there's no reason for them to be real data, or full size. Just generate small samples of your "ten-digit numbers" that represent your conditions and overlaps, and include them in your question labeled appropriately. It's expected for those looking to help you.

Comment: Do something like biglist=[1,2,...100], a_exc=[2, 4, 6...] etc. So that we can understand what is the goal.

Comment: Does the distribution need to be random?

Comment: @NikolasStevenson-Molnar Yes, but that part should be easy; e.g. shuffling the list first.  I even added that into the example.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has three main complications beyond just spreading the items over the lists:

- the exclusion lists prevent simple splitting;
- the exclusion lists themselves may have duplicate exclusions among them, so a simple set-based solution won't work;
- the exclusions lists will allow a solution, but any approach at filling may cause a result list to be prematurely filled with items that could have gone into other lists.

As a result, a solution that works is one that simply tries to add the items to the first list available to them, but if it runs into problems, it just backtracks to the previous addition - and if that ultimately runs into problems, to the previous addition, etc.

In functional languages, this type of backtracking can be implemented very nicely in a recursive function, but since the maximum recursion depth of Python is very limited, an iterative approach is likely better - especially given the size of the data set.

Here's my solution:

```
# generate list of identifiers
biglist = list(range(20))

# arbitrary exclusions, with some duplication
a_exc = [0, 2, 8, 15]
b_exc = [1, 3, 4, 6, 12]
c_exc = [0, 1, 5, 6, 7, 9, 1, 0]


def distribute(xs, n, exclusions):
    # will distribute the contents of list xs over n lists, excluding items from exclusions[m] for the m-th list
    # returns a list of lists (destructive, so xs will be empty after execution, pass in a copy to avoid)

    # initialise result lists
    result = [set() for _ in range(n)]

    # calculate maximum size for each of the list for a balanced distribution
    result_size = len(xs) // n
    if len(xs) % n > 0:
        result_size += 1

    # initialise a list of additions, to allow for backtracking; recursion would be cleaner,
    # but your dataset is too large an Python is not a functional language that is optimised for this
    additions = []

    # add all xs to the lists, trying the list in order, backtracking if lists fill up
    while xs:
        # get the last element from the list
        x = xs.pop()
        # find a place to add it, starting at the first list
        i = 0
        while True:
            while i < n:
                # find a list that's not full and can take x
                if len(result[i]) < result_size and x not in exclusions[i]:
                    # add it
                    result[i].add(x)
                    # remember this exact addition
                    additions.append((i, x))
                    break
                i += 1
            # if x could not be added (due to exclusions and full lists)
            if i == n:
                # put current x back at the end of the list
                xs.append(x)
                # go back to the previous x
                i, x = additions.pop(-1)
                # take it out from the list it was put into
                result[i].remove(x)
                # try putting it in the next list available
                i += 1
            else:
                break
    return result


spread_lists = distribute(biglist, 3, [a_exc, b_exc, c_exc])

print(spread_lists)
```

There's room for optimisation, but I do think this works.

In fact, after generating a few larger test sets, I found the algorithm *needs* optimisation and this is actually quite straightforward: sort the input list by the number of exclusions that match it. So, identifiers that are excluded `n` times are processed before those that are excluded `n-1` times, etc.

This adds the following line to the start of `distribute`:

```
# sort the input by most exclusions, most exclusions last, as list is processed in reverse order
xs = [x for _, x in sorted([([x in exc for exc in exclusions].count(True), x) for x in xs])]
```

This has the added advantage of no longer emptying out `xs`, if that was undesirable.